# Client side JavaScript best practices

Tags: javascript

The only example I can think of for what I am asking is

`<a href="valid.html" onClick="someFunction()>Click Here</a>`

as opposed to

`<a href="javascript:;" onClick="someFunction()>Click Here</a>`

essentially you want your web page to work if the user has JavaScript disabled.

So my question what are some other techniques for handling a user not having JavaScript enabled?

Answer (score 2):

You always want to have your `href` pointing to the proper `url` of the information you want to load in. (I'm assuming that is your goal)

Your `someFunction()` could be an `ajax` call that loads in partial information from the target page. Having `href` setup properly is good for progressive enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

If a user has JavaScript disabled, message that to them. There is **no** reason, in my opinion, to continue development for browsers without JavaScript support, or users that have it disabled.

On to the answer to your question...

```
function someFunction() { }

// using jquery
$(document).ready(function() {
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for(i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
        // more logic could go here
        $(els[i]).click(function() { someFunction(); });
    }
});
```

```
<a id="optional" href="/link/to/page">Click Here</a>
```

Comment: If JS is *essential to your app* (that is, if you're building a super-ajaxy web app that's useless without JS, as opposed to a web site), then i'd agree.  But for most sites, it's better if it works with JS disabled, and you just use JS to add some extra spiff.  Googlebot doesn't speak JS, you know.

Comment: @cHao I agree with you entirely -- I forgot to mention that I was specifically speaking about dynamic web applications.